# How can I scale every image in a list?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Im having trouble on scaling every image in this list using a for loop, when I run it no scaling occurs. This is my list and my for loop:

self.pokemon = [
pygame.image.load('/Users/gersh/PycharmProjects/snakeeo/venv/lib/resources/pokemon/bulbasaur.png').convert(),
pygame.image.load('/Users/gersh/PycharmProjects/snakeeo/venv/lib/resources/pokemon/caterpie.png').convert(),
pygame.image.load('/Users/gersh/PycharmProjects/snakeeo/venv/lib/resources/pokemon/charmander.png').convert(),
pygame.image.load('/Users/gersh/PycharmProjects/snakeeo/venv/lib/resources/pokemon/pidgey.png').convert(),
pygame.image.load('/Users/gersh/PycharmProjects/snakeeo/venv/lib/resources/pokemon/squirtle.png').convert()

```
def set_colorkey(self):
    for pokemon in self.pokemon:
        pokemon.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        pygame.transform.scale(pokemon, (120,120))

                    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) does not scale the image itself, but returns a new scaled image:

```py
for i in range(len(self.pokemon)):
    image = self.pokemon[i]
    image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
    self.pokemon[i] = pygame.transform.scale(image, (120,120))
```